# GitVersion not incrementing versions for NuGet setup

Tags: git, nuget, semantic-versioning, gitversion

I'm struggling to get a GitVersion config working for the way we want a NuGet repo to work. Changes need to be committed to `feature/*` branches, and then merged back onto `main`. Unfortunately, none of the `+semver: xxx` comments on our commits are doing anything. We tried using the new Mainline config, but that doesn't seem to work either. Can anyone spot what's wrong with this config please?

[image: Repo commits]

**Our GitVersion.yml file:**

```
mode: ContinuousDelivery
next-version: 1.0.0
branches:
  {}
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}
```

**/showConfig**:

```
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: ContinuousDelivery
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ci
next-version: 1.0.0
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
tag-pre-release-weight: 60000
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
branches:
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: alpha
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    regex: ^dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    source-branches: []
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 0
  main:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^master$|^main$
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
  release:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: None
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^releases?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - support
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^features?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - release
    - feature
    - support
    - hotfix
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  pull-request:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: PullRequest
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)'
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^(pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - release
    - feature
    - support
    - hotfix
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  hotfix:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - support
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  support:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^support[/-]
    source-branches:
    - main
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
ignore:
  sha: []
commit-date-format: yyyy-MM-dd
merge-message-formats: {}
update-build-number: true
```

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this yet? I suspect you might have better luck with https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues. Are feature branches even supported by GitVersion?

Comment: Actually, this link my be the place: https://gitter.im/GitTools/GitVersion

Answer (score 3):

Remove `next-version` (do a `git tag 1.0.0` on the appropriate commit instead) and change `mode` to `Mainline` and this should work.